# enhanced usage of question mark in java

Tags: java

`last = cur = cur == null ? head : cur.link;`

I am trying to understand this using if and else statement.
But I am stuck on this one.
Can anyone help this out

Comment: Sure.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: The title should probably be "abuse of the ternary operator feat. simultaneous assignments".

Comment: Yeah that is one truly abusive statement.

Answer (score 5):

Your expression is equal to

```
if (cur == null) {
    cur = head;
} else {
    cur = cur.link;
}
last = cur;
```

You can split the example into two parts for easier understanding. **Part 1**:

```
last = cur = xxx;
```

is the same as

```
cur = xxx;
last = cur;
```

**Part 2**:

```
cur = cur == null ? head : cur.link;
```

is the same as

```
if (cur == null) {
    cur = head;
} else {
    cur = cur.link;
}
```

And **part 2** would be even easier to understand if `cur` didn't appear three times. So this is simpler:

```
a = b == null ? c : d;
```

is the same as

```
if (b == null) {
    a = c;
} else {
    a = d;
}
```

Comment: `last = cur = xxx;` is only the same as `last = xxx; cur = xxx;` if `xxx` has no side-effects and evaluates to the same thing every time (which is not the case for `last = cur = cur + 1` or `last = cur = myList.add(1)` for example). It's always the same as `cur = xxx; last = cur;`, which you used in your rewrite of the example one-liner.

Comment: @Raniz, I stand corrected. Thanks.I've now updated the answer.